# how to update seller profile in django?

Tags: python, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am working on a multiuser project which has two types of users.

1st is a seller and 2nd is the buyer. When a seller registers itself then it will be redirected to his profile where seller can update its profile by providing extra credentials like first name, last name, address etc. but the main problem which I am getting is that when I provide data to be updated it shows nothing.

So I request you all to provide me with the best solution. I have to submit this work before Sunday night.

I am also providing you with my code so that you all can understand where I am wrong.

`models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from accounts.models import Seller


class Profile(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/')
    date_of_birth =  models.DateField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # zip = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # country = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(Seller, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Note: I have another app named accounts in which I have two models 1st Seller and 2nd Buyer which have `OneToOne` relation with `User`.

acounts app models:

```
class Buyer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='buyer_profile')
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/', null=True, blank=True)
    date_of_birth =  models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.user:
            return str(self.user.username)
        else:
            return 'Buyer Name is null'


class Seller(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='seller_profile')
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/', null=True, blank=True)
    date_of_birth =  models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.user:
            return str(self.user.username)
        else:
            return 'Seller Name is null'
```

`views.py`:

```
def seller_update_view(request):
    user = request.user
    seller = request.user.profile # I also get error here. 
    print("Update profile",seller)
    user_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=user)
    profile_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=seller)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        profile_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=seller)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            return redirect('settings')
    return render(request, 'settings.html', {
            'user_form': user_form,
            'profile_form': profile_form,
        })
```

`forms.py`:

```
from InMay.models import Profile, Event
from django import forms
from accounts.models import User  # I am importing it from accounts app

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'profile_image', 'date_of_birth','gender', 'phone', 'address']


class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'username']
```

`settings.html`:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    <main>
        <div class="preloader bg-dark flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="position-relative">
        <img src="{% static 'assets/img/brand/light-without-letter.svg' %}" alt="Logo loader">
        <img src="{% static 'assets/img/brand/letter.svg' %}" class="rotate-letter" alt="Letter loader">
    </div>
</div>

        <div class="section section-lg bg-soft">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row pt-5 pt-md-0">
                
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 d-none d-lg-block">
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <div class="card border-light p-2">
        <div class="card-body p-2">
            <div class="profile-thumbnail small-thumbnail mx-auto">
                <img src="{% static 'assets/img/team/profile-picture-4.jpg' %}" class="card-img-top rounded-circle border-white" alt="Joseph Portrait">
                <img src="{{user.seller.profile_form.profile_image.url}}" class="card-img-top rounded-circle border-white" alt="Dynamic Image">
            </div>
            <h5 class="h5 font-weight-normal text-center mt-3 mb-0">{{profile_form.first_name}} {{profile_form.last_name}}</h5>
            <div class="list-group dashboard-menu list-group-sm mt-4">
                <a href="./account.html" class="d-flex list-group-item list-group-item-action ">Overview <span class="icon icon-xs ml-auto"><span class="fas fa-chevron-right"></span></span> </a>
                <a href="" class="d-flex list-group-item list-group-item-action  active ">Settings<span class="icon icon-xs ml-auto"><span class="fas fa-chevron-right"></span></span> </a>
                <a href="./my-items.html" class="d-flex list-group-item list-group-item-action ">My Items<span class="icon icon-xs ml-auto"><span class="fas fa-chevron-right"></span></span> </a>
                <a href="./security.html" class="d-flex list-group-item list-group-item-action ">Security<span class="icon icon-xs ml-auto"><span class="fas fa-chevron-right"></span></span> </a>
                <a href="./billing.html" class="d-flex list-group-item list-group-item-action ">Billing<span class="icon icon-xs ml-auto"><span class="fas fa-chevron-right"></span></span> </a>
                <a href="./messages.html" class="d-flex list-group-item list-group-item-action  border-0">Messages<span class="icon icon-xs ml-auto"><span class="fas fa-chevron-right"></span></span> </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-12 d-lg-none">
    <div class="card bg-white border-light mb-4 mb-lg-5">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="col-10 d-flex">
                    <a href="./account.html" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action border-0 ">Overview</a>
                    <a href="{% url 'settings' %}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action border-0  active ">Settings</a>
                    <a href="./my-items.html" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-none d-sm-block border-0 ">My Items</a>
                    <a href="./security.html" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-none d-md-block border-0 ">Security</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2 d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <div class="btn-group dropleft">
                        <button class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split mr-2 m-0 p-0" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="icon icon-sm">
                                <span class="fas fa-ellipsis-h icon-secondary fa-lg"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <a href="./my-items.html" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-sm-none border-0 ">My Items</a>
                            <a href="./security.html" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-md-none border-0 ">Security</a>
                            <a href="./billing.html" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action border-0 ">Billing</a>
                            <a href="./messages.html" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action border-0 ">Messages</a> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

                    <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 mb-5">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="card card-body bg-white border-light mb-4">
                                    <h2 class="h5 mb-4">General information</h2>
                                    <form  action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        <div>
                                            <label for="profile_image">Profile Picture</label>
                                            <input id="profile_image" name="img" style="border-style:none;" type="file" class="form-control">
                                            {{profile_form.profile_image}}
                                        </div><br>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
                                                    <input class="form-control" name="first_name" id="first_name" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
                                                    {{profile_form.first_name}}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
                                                    <input class="form-control" name="last_name" id="last_name" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
                                                    {{profile_form.last_name}}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row align-items-center">
                                            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="birthday">Birthday</label>
                                                    <input type="text" name="birthday" class="form-control flatpickr-input" id="birthday" data-toggle="date" placeholder="Select your birth date">
                                                    {{profile_form.date_of_birth}}
                                                    </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3 col-lg-9">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="gender">Gender</label>
                                                    <select class="custom-select" name="gender" id="gender" required>
                                                        
                                                        <option value="Female">Female</option>
                                                    
                                                        
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                                                    <input class="form-control" name="email" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email">
                                                    {{user_form.email}}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                                                    <input class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone">
                                                    {{profile_form.phone}}
                                                    
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <h2 class="h5 my-4">Address</h2>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-9 mb-3">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="address">Address</label>
                                                    <input class="form-control" name="address" id="address" type="text" placeholder="Your address">
                                                    {{profile_form.address}}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- <div class="col-sm-3 mb-3">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="number">Number</label>
                                                    <input class="form-control" name="number" id="number" type="number" placeholder="No.">
                                                </div>
                                            </div> -->
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <!-- <div class="col-sm-4 mb-3">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="city">City</label>
                                                    <input class="form-control" name="city" id="city" type="text" placeholder="City">
                                                </div>
                                            </div> -->
                                            <!-- <div class="col-sm-4 mb-3">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="country">Country</label>
                                                    <select name="country" class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible" id="country" data-toggle="select" title="Country" data-live-search="true" data-live-search-placeholder="Country" data-select2-id="1" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                                                        <option value="United Stated">United Stated</option>
                                                        <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
                                                        <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
                                                        <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
                                                        <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
                                                        <option value="UK">UK</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div> -->
                                            <!-- <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="zip">ZIP</label>
                                                    <input class="form-control" name="zip" id="zip" type="tel" placeholder="ZIP">
                                                </div>
                                            </div> -->
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="mt-3">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save All</button>
                                            
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <!-- <div class="card card-body bg-white border-light">
                                    <h2 class="h5 mb-4">Alerts & Notifications</h2>
                                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                                        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between pl-0 border-bottom">
                                            <div>
                                                <h3 class="h6 mb-1">Company News</h3>
                                                <span class="small">Get Spaces news, announcements, and product updates</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                                                <div class="custom-control custom-switch"><input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="shop-notification-1" checked="checked"> <label class="custom-control-label" for="shop-notification-1"></label></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between pl-0 border-bottom">
                                            <div>
                                                <h3 class="h6 mb-1">Account Activity</h3>
                                                <span class="small">Get important notifications about you or activity you've missed</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                                                <div class="custom-control custom-switch"><input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="shop-notification-2"> <label class="custom-control-label" for="shop-notification-2"></label></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between pl-0">
                                            <div>
                                                <h3 class="h6 mb-1">Meetups Near You</h3>
                                                <span class="small">Get an email when a Dribbble Meetup is posted close to my location</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                                                <div class="custom-control custom-switch"><input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="shop-notification-3" checked="checked"> <label class="custom-control-label" for="shop-notification-3"></label></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                 </div> -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you've got an issue in that the relationships you reference don't actually exist. So the instance you load for `ProfileUpdateForm` won't be correct.

For example;

`seller = request.user.profile`

A user doesn't have a `Profile` object, a `Seller` does though. And a `Seller` is it's own object, so setting `seller = request.user.profile` doesn't make sense as a `seller` variable.

Your view would make more sense looking something like;

```
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden


def seller_update_view(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()

    user = request.user
    try:
        seller = user.seller
        profile = seller.profile
    except AttributeError:
        # Create a seller & profile for the user
        seller = Seller.objects.create(user=user)
        profile = Profile.objects.create(seller=seller)

    print("Update profile", profile)

    user_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=user)
    profile_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=profile)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        profile_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            return redirect('settings')

    return render(request, 'settings.html', {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'profile_form': profile_form,
    })
```

Comment: is is still giving me the same error. 'User' object has no attribute 'seller'.

Comment: Then you probably should 403 users who aren't a `Seller`

Comment: I've updated with an example of throwing a 403 and creating a seller & profile object when they don't exist for the user.

Answer (score 0):

I redesign models.py, forms.py file below:-

```
models.py # Profile models have all field (contains Buyers and Sellers)

class Profile(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, 
           on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    # is_seller field divide the user from Seller and Buyer

    is_seller = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # if 'is_seller' field false then it means user is 'buyer' and vice-versa

    
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/', blank=True, null=True)
    date_of_birth =  models.DateField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    # city = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    # number = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    # zip = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    # country = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
```

Now in forms.py file add required fields according to user(that is user is buyer or seller):-

```
forms.py

class BuyersForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [# Choose and add fields for buyers here]

class SellerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [# Choose and add fields for seller here]
```

Now, in frontend write custom registration page for login(that is, First name, Last name, username, Email, Password),and there must be a selector (to choose seller or buyer).When user click on submit then save all values to `User`(that is, First name, Last name, username, Email, Password)  as well as in `Profile`(that is, is_seller is True or False and also add User instance).
After that (suppose user chooses `seller` then) send the `SellerForm` in Frontend and ask user to fill the required filled.

BUT there are also another way (that is by using `proxy` model) if you want more information on proxy model then go to this link:- [click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f0hdXr2MOEA)

Comment: thank you for helping me. I will try to apply this method. I will tell you tomorrow about it that how your solution worked.

Comment: if you have any confusion/question, let me know

Comment: okat I'll let you know. can you give me your email?

Comment: @djangodeveloper eeak911345@gmail.com